# Negative Margin-Top Not Working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a transparent `nav` using `Bootstrap` with an image that has a `margin-top: -100px` CSS value so it shows under the navbar.  It renders properly in IE:
[image]

But for some reason the image isn't recognizing the negative `margin-top` in Chrome:
[image]

My HTML is slightly complicated, but needs to be that way (for a variety of reasons):

```
<div class="hero-image-row">
  <div class="hero-image-outer text-center">
    <div class="hero-image-inner text-center">
      <%= image_tag 'Background 1.jpg', class: "hero-image",alt: "Delicious-looking hot dogs on a manly grill. Just like God intended." %>
    </div> <!-- hero-image-inner -->
  </div> <!-- hero-image-inner -->
</div> <!-- row -->
```

And my CSS is as follows:

```
/* NAVIGATION */

 #custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar {
   margin-bottom: 0px !important;
 }

 #custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: black;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: $font-typewriter;
    background-color: $transparent-white !important;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: black;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: black;
    background-color: $transparent-black !important;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: black;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: $transparent-black;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus .icon-bar {
    background-color: $transparent-black;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: black !important;
}

#custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background: black !important; 
}


/* HEROS */

.hero-image-row {
   margin-top: -50px !important;
   overflow-x: hidden !important;
   width: 100% !important;
 }

.hero-image-outer {
   width: 300%;
   height: 400px;
   overflow-y: hidden !important;
 }

 .hero-image-inner {
   width: 66%;
   overflow-x: hidden !important;
 }

 .hero-image {
   height: 400px;
   margin-left: -50%;
   z-index: 0 !important;
 }

 @media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
   .hero-image-outer {
     width: 100%;
   }

   .hero-image-inner {
     width: 100%;
     height: 400px;
   }

   .hero-image {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     margin-left: 0%;
   }
 }

 .overlap-hero-image {
   margin-top: -300px;
   height: 300px;
 }

 .height-auto {
   height: auto !important;
 }
```

Can anyone help me diagnose why Chrome is acting up here?  I have used similar code on other sites and have never had an issue.  I have tried it with and without the SCSS variables for transparency, so I know that's not the issue. It really is something with the margin.

**ADDED NAVBAR CODE:**

```
<div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="/">The Manly Art of BBQ</a>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="/products">Man Rules</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about-us">BBQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">My Mancard</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- collapse -->
  </div> <!-- container-fluid -->
</div> <!-- custom-bootstrap-menu -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing it using this for the top navbar to remove it from the flow:

```
#custom-bootstrap-menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This does not answer to the question itself, you simply found another method. I am facing a similar issue and it can not be solved with `position: absolute` in any case.

Answer (score 2):

Use webkit.

Add the following code after your current margin code.

```
-webkit-margin-before: -100px;
```

Comment: Still hasn't changed with `.hero-image-row {
   margin-top: -100px !important;
   -webkit-margin-before: -100px !important;`.  I've tried with and without `!important` as well.

Comment: Inspect the element and see what it's margin-top is set to under the 'Computed' tab under it's CSS. It may be set to some value that isn't `-100px`, then you can identify what is causing it to not be positioned upwards.

Comment: The computed tab shows `-100px` and it works properly in IE.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add the following CSS to the element you want to apply negative margin to:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

That simple!

For your specific example:

```
.hero-image-row {
   margin-top: -50px !important;
   overflow-x: hidden !important;
   width: 100% !important;
   vertical-align: top;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some code for you, Copy the below code to your test html page and see the output.
Hope this work.

```css
.navbar-default{
  background:rgba(255,255,255, 0.4);
  background-image:none;
  border-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

  
    <img src="http://feelgrafix.com/data/wallpaper-hd/Wallpaper-HD-16.jpg" class="img-responsive first-slide" alt="First slide">
```

Comment: ...and if I want it to disappear when the user scrolls down?